# Generic Return type : How to catch a return type from many possible return types?

Tags: java

Writing the title was a bit tricky for this question :p
This is a basic java query!
I am using google cloud and it has different methods, such as launchInstance, listInstances and terminateInstance and so on.. Here, launchInstance will return a type String as Success or Fail, listInstances will return ArrayList, and so forth.

Now, I want a generic return type, so I made a class which has data entries such as status, reason, and dataRequired which will eventually send the data that is required, i.e String or ArrayList or HashMap.
How can I achieve this functionality.
Here is sample code that I was thinking of doing:

```
public class ResponseHelper {

    private String status;
    private String reason;
    private String type;
    private Object data;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }
    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void dataRequired(Object data) {
        switch(getType()) {
        case "ArrayList": this.data=(ArrayList<String>)data;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: instead of `switch(getType())` why don't you use `if (data instanceof ArrayList)` and so on

Comment: The cast in `dataRequired` is pointless, since `this.data` is of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Generic return type of any object in Java, just return Object as the type.(Instead of creating a separate new class for it) Then you can check which object it is and do your stuff. Below is a simple program that you can get an idea out of it

```
public class GenericReturn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object output = returnMeSomething(2);
        System.out.println(output.getClass().getSimpleName());
        output = returnMeSomething(1);
        System.out.println(output.getClass().getSimpleName());
        output = returnMeSomething(0);
        System.out.println(output.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    /** This can return any Object you want as it has Object as return type*/
    public static Object returnMeSomething(int num) {
        if (num == 1) {
            return "Test";
        }
        else if (num == 2) {
            return new HashMap();
        } 
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

This output as below

```
HashMap
String
ArrayList
```